# Django custom model field do work after save

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got a custom model field `class VaultField(CharField):` which is used like:

```py
class MyClass:
  secret = VaultField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

It should save that field's value to HashiCorp Vault and store the Vault path in the database.

That's all nice and easy when the Vault path is static, but what I'd like to do is to build the Vault path based on the model instance ID.

But none of the methods `from_db_value`, `to_python`, `get_prep_value` are being called post save and therefore don't have any data about the instance.

Is there any way to run field code post save?

To get the path `/fields/[my-class-name]/[my-class-id]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I wanted but it works fine with `uuid`, so I'll leave it there.

Now my Vault path is:

```py
return f"vault-fields/{self.model.__name__}/{self.name}/{uuid.uuid4()}"
```

Where `self.model.__name__` is the name of the class and `self.name` is the name of the field being saved.

Ends up being a Vault path like `vault-fields/MyClass/secret/c894295a-9715-4854-afda-83254b16ffba`.